# storing user data in firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling, dart-null-safety

i want to add user data to the firebase using firestore ,i am watching toutial form udemy but due to firestore update i face this error(The method 'document' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'document'.)

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(userCredential.user?.uid)//The method 'document' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'document'.
                .setData({
              'username': username,
              'email': email,
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document` is changed to `doc` and `setDocument` to `set`

Here is correct code:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(userCredential.user?.uid)
                .set({
                  'username': username,
                  'email': email,
                });
```

Comment: I would also suggest you to look into this documentation. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/